# C# Disposable Context as Method Parameter

Tags: c#, performance, garbage-collection, dispose

I have a question about IDisposable Method parameters. 
Assume i have got a class which implements the IDisposable Interface, such as "TestClass":

```cs
class TestClass : IDisposable
{
   public void TestMethod()
   {
     Console.WriteLine("I am a Test Method");
   }

   public void Dispose()
   {
     Console.WriteLine("Test Method was disposed!");
   }
}
```

Suppose I want to put a instance of IDisposable Class (e.g. DB Context) into a method to perform context dependent actions.
Usually we use this like in the following example:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   using (var context = new TestClass())
   {
      X(context);
   }
}

public static void X(TestClass context)
{
  context.TestMethod();
}
```

The result is, as expected, that the Dispose() method is called. (Debugger attached, or displayed "Test Method was disposed!" on Console)

So the question is:
If i will write something like this:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{   
   X(new TestClass());
}
```

I cannot see any indicator that the Dispose method has been called? Is the TestClass() context automatically disposed of if the execution of the method was successful / finished.

Is the dispose method called when the garbage collector cleans this up? 
I am concerned that resource-intensive contexts will still be open?

Comment: dispose and GC are not the same things. If you're passing a disposable to another method, there has to be an agreement that either the caller or the callee disposes of it. Usually you'd expect the caller (unless documented otherwise) of normal functions to dispose and so they shouldn't just inline a `new TastClass()` into the method call in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The garbage collector can only clean up *managed resources* (things created with `new`). Classes that work with *unmanaged resources* typically implement a finalizer/destructor, that calls `Dispose()` for you when you haven't already. The garbage collector does call the finalizer. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose) for an example and more information.

If you don't explicitly call `Dispose()` and your class does not have a destructor, `Dispose()` won't be called at all. This shouldn't be a problem, because at that point the garbage collector is already cleaning up anyway.

So for classes that do not own unmanaged resources, `Dispose()` just gives control over *when* resources are to be freed.